# How to change JPanel color with ActionListener from another class?

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, jpanel, actionlistener

I am having issues changing the color of a Jpanel (mainPanel) in one of my classes using an ActionListener for a radio button in a different class. I have the default color for mainPanel set to black.

Essentially I have a setMainPanel method in my first class:

```
public class MainBoard extends JFrame{

    public void setMainPanel(Color c){
        mainPanel.setBackground(c);
    }
}
```

In my second class I have my action listener as:

```
private class MenuHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == exit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(e.getSource() == blueBackground) {
            MainBoard mb = new MainBoard();
            mb.setMainPanel(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
}
```

My System.exit command will work if I click "Exit" in my menu. The concept I am trying to accomplish is to have a "Change Color" menu with radio buttons where the user can change to Black or Blue. I know this is probably overkill, but we are trying to learn how to make changes for components from different classes.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No good:

```
MainBoard mb = new MainBoard();  // this is not the currently displayed MainBoard
mb.setMainPanel(Color.BLUE);
```

This represents a common Java newbie error of magical thinking where you think that changing the state of an object of a class will magically change the state of a different object of the same class, but this is not how Java works.  You need to call the `setMainPanel(...)` method on a reference to the currently *displayed* or active MainBoard instance, not some random new and totally distinct MainBoard object that you create within this method and which is never displayed.

So pass in the appropriate reference into the listener, perhaps using something like:

```
private class MenuHandler implements ActionListener {
    MainBoard mainBoard;

    MenuHandler(MainBoard mainBoard) {
        this.mainBoard = mainBoard;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == exit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(e.getSource() == blueBackground) {
            // MainBoard mb = new MainBoard();
            mainBoard.setMainPanel(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
}
```